# PHP return the value but false

Tags: php

I have this simple function:

```
function isMember($uID, $pdo) {
$status = getUserStatus($uID, $pdo);
    if(isAllowed($status['status']))
            return $status['status'];
    return false;
}
```

Now I am looking for a way to return false yes, but to return also the value of the variable.

I tried the following, but it makes it empty anyway:

```
return $status['status'] == false;
```

So the logi is return false anyway but give me back also the value of the variable, even if it's false, because false should not mean empty :)

Comment: You want `return $status['status'] == false;` (notice the double equal sign).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return an array, and use the `list()` method to get your results:

```
function isMember($uID, $pdo) {
    $status = getUserStatus($uID, $pdo);

    $statusString = $status['status'];
    $statusFlag = false;
    if(isAllowed($status['status']))
       $statusFlag = true;

    return array($statusFlag,statusString);
}

//usage
list($flag,$msg) = isMember(5,"whatever");
echo "Access: $flag, with message $msg";
```

Answer (score 1):

A function can not return multiple values, but similar results can be obtained by (1) returning an array or by (2) passing a variable by reference and storing the value you want returned in that variable.

1. You will need to write your function in a way that it returns an array containing the following:

   - The value you wan't returned
   - A flag that signifies true/false
2. Pass a variable by reference into your function and store the value of the status in that variable.

```
    function isMember($uID, $pdo, &statByRef) {

    $status = getUserStatus($uID, $pdo);

        if(isAllowed($status['status'])) {

                return $status['status'];

        }

        $statByRef = $status['status']; 
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: Sorry all, couldn't get the last function to format correctly.

Comment: Fixed it with <pre><code></pre></code> the text editor wasn't formatting correctly :)

Answer (score 0):

False returns empty in PHP, see http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

From documentation: 
Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try using something like this:

```
function isMember($uID, $pdo) {
$status = getUserStatus($uID, $pdo);
    if(isAllowed($status['status'])){
            return $status['status'];
    }
    return false;
} // If isAllowed returns true, then PHP will return $Status['Status'];, if not then PHP will by default return false.
```

I have noticed you haven't used braces which makes the code a little awkward to debug. Then validate like:

```
if (isMember($Var,$AnotherVar) !== false){
 //isMember has not returned false, so PHP is operating within these braces
}
```

Such a simple thing, which should be most effective.

---

If your wanting to assign true/false to $status['status']; then you are performing the right method, but wrong operator.

`==` is a comparision operator. Not assignment

`=` is an assignment operator, so your assignment should be:

`$status['status'] = false;`